# How can I configure webpack.config.js to convert/transform my HTML file into JS in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, owl-carousel

Here is my folder structure

[image]

when i tried to run my react app it give me this error
Failed to compile.

./src/css/owl.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> 

I tried google it and it says i need to create manual loader to load my html file. It is regarding to webpack but I don't know how and where I configure loader to load the owl.html file.

Comment: Please add the webpack config you currently have if any, if not do tell!

Comment: I have added 3 dependencies webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin. but I haven't configured webpack. frankly speaking I don't know where and how I configure it

Comment: No issues, do let me know of you are using create-react-app?

Comment: Also, why you have a owl.html in your css folder?

Comment: there is already a HTML file provided in the public folder in your directory structure, which will be used as the final HTML file loaded in browser after all the compilation.
Do you have some other use case where you need this owl.html?

Comment: Yes I have used create-react-app for creating react app. and I am converting html template into react and in html template the owl.html file is inside css folder that's why i copied it inside my react project css folder.

Comment: Alright, let me answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

No, you can not simply convert your HTML/CSS/JS in to React JS through a plugin.

There is no need of `webpack` her, as it is already provided and packed by `create-react-app`, you can simple create a component of your page template provided.

**Long Answer:**

React project architecture says, One has to create a React JS component for every UI page/segment/section/widget. So for creating a page in react from the html file provided you simple has to crate a component file called `Owl.js` in the `components` folder.

In the `Owl.js` write the following:

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => { 
  return (
    <React.Fragment>enter code here
      // paste the code from your owl.html file. (everything that is written under <body>)
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Use this newly created component in the `App.js` you have by importing it into.

Also use the css by importing it simply in the `Owl.js` file, like this:

```
import '~you-path~/owl.css';
```

And finally to make all the JS written in `owl.js` you have to carefully integrate the functions, listeners and data you are using in the newly created component out of the return statement.

I hope this clears the confusion here.

Comment: Thank you for giving me good explanation about my problem. I will try your solution. Hope it will help me solve my problem.

Comment: Sure, So let me know if anything else caught you in confusion!